# Database Design to persist changing wizard/workflow data?

Tags: sql-server, xml, entity-framework, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I need to create a wizard type web application to acquire data for a report. There are multiple sections so multiple wizard workflows. In addition a workflow could change ie a step could be added.

I am considering the best database design, and started with a traditional "ER design" with explicit column names as is always recommended. I have been researching EAV with interest . However I now realise that I do have a problem with an explicit design when a workflow can change. So my current thinking is

1) EAV with the use of Views (with "instead of" trigger for updates)
2) Simply persist each step dataset as XML.

Both present query issues, but I guess 1) is better although one could do string querying on XML using "Like" etc.

I am also using MVC 3 and EF5, and would wish to leverage their facilities as much as possible and not "fight" the technology.

I may also need to use some form of XML config file to help setup the razor view with the correct controls/layout.

I would really appreciate some wisdom on the above.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into Windows Workflow Foundation as well? You can [build a wizard](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-233b5e3c) using that, and will gain persistability, reliability, and a shiny workflow designer out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hi RB, Thanks for the reply. Yes I have looked at it and may end up using it, but decided to stay away from it to keep things simple. I think even with WF one has to decide on how one is going to persist the data either explicitly, generically(ie EAV) or via XML. I have to admit I have 2 issues here, 1) getting the correct UI for the step, and 2) getting the right DB design to persist the step data. I am really focussing on 2) in this question.

Comment: With WF you just store a user's workflow to persistent storage (e.g. a database using [SqlWorkflowPersistenceService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.hosting.sqlworkflowpersistenceservice.aspx)). There's some good [blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2008/12/09/understanding-persistence-in-windows-workflow-foundation.aspx) covering both [theory](http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2005/10/05/426699.aspx) and [practice](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103592/WF-4-Persistence-Tracking-and-Bookmarks-A-Practice)

Comment: Hi RB, Thks again. I realise that you persist the WF ie what status the WF is in etc, but what about the actual details of the object that one is acquiring data on via the workflow ie Order. The attributes of order may be filled out over 5 steps. So persistence of the Workflow is seperate to persistence of the data object(order) being worked on. I believe that it is correct. I will check out your links. Thks

Comment: Also for me, WF4 has become a more attractive proposition particularly as it is XAML based rather than pure code. I think WF4 is a redesign/rebuild of WF Foundation.

Comment: As I thought, "SqlWorkflowPersistenceService" - "Represents a persistence service that uses a SQL database to store workflow state information." I still need store my Order in its tables.... although in my case my data object ie Report Section can have variable attributes depending on workflow.